# Convert number to month name in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have this PHP code:

```
$monthNum = sprintf("%02s", $result["month"]);
$monthName = date("F", strtotime($monthNum));

echo $monthName;
```

But it's returning `December` rather than `August`.

`$result["month"]` is equal to 8, so the `sprintf` function is adding a `0` to make it `08`.

Comment: Unless you convert this to a full date (08-21-2013), or something that would closely resemble a date `strtotime` has no idea what your trying to do. Alternatively just use a switch for something like this.

Comment: sorry - the $result["month"] is 8 because i have an SQL Query that says select MONTH(date time) from table... so in the table its a full date format

Comment: But `strtotime` has no idea what "8" means. `strtotime` parses complete timestamps like "2012-05-12 08:43:12". What does "8" mean in this context?

Comment: why not just: `echo date( "F", time() );` ?  For example, `echo date( "F", strtotime("2019-03-09") );` will output "March"

Answer (score 427, accepted):

**The recommended way to do this:**

Nowadays, you should really be using DateTime objects for any date/time math. This requires you to have a PHP version >= 5.2. As shown in [Glavić's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467880/1438393), you can use the following:

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
```

The [`!` formatting character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is used to reset everything to the [Unix epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20822821/1438393). The `m` format character is the numeric representation of a month, with leading zeroes.

**Alternative solution:**

If you're using an older PHP version and can't upgrade at the moment, you could this solution.
The second parameter of [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function accepts a timestamp, and you could use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) to create one, like so:

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10)); // March
```

If you want the 3-letter month name like `Mar`, change `F` to `M`. The list of all available formatting options can be found in [the PHP manual documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: This doesn't respect the LC_TIME locale and will always output the month name in English.

Comment: I never saw this on SO - 
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Noone from 48 pluses didnt have this?

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit: Could you post the code which you're having issues with? In https://eval.in/ or some similar pastebin site?

Comment: Why do you say that we "should really" be using DateTime objects for this?  DateTime objects are useful, but the date() function is much simpler as has much lower overhead (in terms of both speed and memory) if all you're trying to do is something simple like this.

Comment: @orrd:  If the speed difference between date() and DateTime turns out to be the bottleneck of the application you're building, I'd say you have bigger problems to worry about. For actual applications, where you are inevitably going to need to do other things with the dates, then having it be in an object is a superior as it's got a easier to read API.

Comment: @orrd: Kinda surprised merely suggesting DateTime warrants a downvote :P So much for DRY: http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html

Comment: Thanks for the "!" part - PHP does some really unexpected things without that bit :)

Comment: $monthNum  = date('m')+1;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F');  It works fine, add or minus to monthNum brings the desired result. Whereas $monthNum = date('m')-2;

$monthName = date("F", strtotime($monthNum));

echo $monthName; It gives wrong results,

Answer (score 44):

Just because everyone is using strtotime() and date() functions, I will show [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) example:

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $result['month']);
echo $dt->format('F');
```

Comment: Alternately, you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat('m|', $result['month']);` to reset only fields that are missing.

Comment: Is there a way to change the language using this solution?

Comment: @MichelAyres: Nope. You will have to use `strftime()` for that.

Answer (score 38):

Use `mktime()`:

```
<?php
 $monthNum = 5;
 $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
 echo $monthName; // Output: May
?>
```

See the PHP manual : http://php.net/mktime

Comment: Is there any way to get month number when month name is passed ?

Comment: @Nisha use paramter `"m"` it will return the month as a 2 digit number as a `string`.  e.g. January = 01, February = 02

Answer (score 27):

**IntlDateFormatter::format**

To do the conversion in respect of a specific locale, you can use the `IntlDateFormatter` class:

```
function getMonthName ($locale, $monthNumber) {
    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale);
    $formatter->setPattern('MMMM');

    return $formatter->format(mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber));
}

$monthName = getMonthName('fr_FR', 8); // août
```

This requires the intl extension. The class is available in PHP 5.3.0+.

**Historical - before PHP 8.1.0**

*Before the IntlDateFormatter class, the `strftime` function was used. This function has been deprecated in PHP 8.1.0.*

To do the conversion in respect of the current locale, you can use the `strftime` function:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');                                              
$monthName = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber));
```

`date` doesn't respect the locale, `strftime` does.

Comment: Thanks, working nice! However, I had to use `$monthName = utf8_encode(strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber)));` in order to display accentuated characters like in 'Août'

Comment: @Roubi As utf8_encode is documented as "Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8", it means your û was an ISO-8859-1. If you want UTF-8 everywhere (and your PHP code doesn't run by default in UTF-8), you can use LC_ALL instead of LC_TIME in setlocale.

Comment: strftime  is now deprecated

Comment: @shelbypereira Indeed, the IntlDateFormatter class can be now used instead. Updating the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 22):

[`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects a standard date format, and passes back a timestamp.

You seem to be passing [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) a single digit to output a date format from.

You should be using [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) which takes the date elements as parameters.

#### Your full code:

```
$monthNum = sprintf("%02s", $result["month"]);
$monthName = date("F", mktime(null, null, null, $monthNum));

echo $monthName;
```

However, the mktime function does not require a leading zero to the month number, so the first line is completely unnecessary, and `$result["month"]` can be passed straight into the function.

This can then all be combined into a single line, echoing the date inline.

#### Your refactored code:

```
echo date("F", mktime(null, null, null, $result["month"], 1));
```

...

Comment: Strangely `date("F", mktime(null, null, null, 2));` returns `March` instead of `February`.

Comment: Well noticed, @Mischa. If you don't set a day (the 5th parameter), `mktime` will use the current day. Today is 31st. What is the 31st February? :)

Comment: There is an error in your refactored code. `1` isn't being provided as 5th parameter to `mktime` but as 3rd parameter to `date` which would not produce expected results

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to print a month from the given number. Pick one suite for you.

**1. date() function along with parameter 'F'**

Code example:

```
$month_num = 10;
echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_num, 10)); //output: October
```

**2. By creating php date object using createFromFormat()**

Code Example

```
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
echo "month name: ".$dateObj->format('F'); // Output: October
```

**3. strtotime() function**

```
echo date("F", strtotime('00-'.$monthNum.'-01')); // Output: October
```

**4. mktime() function**

```
echo date("F", mktime(null, null, null, $monthNum)); // Output: October
```

**5. By using jdmonthname()**

```
$jd=gregoriantojd($monthNum,10,2019);
echo jdmonthname($jd,0); // Output: Oct
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have the month number, you can first create a date from it with a default date of 1st and default year of the current year, then extract the month name from the date created:

```
echo date("F", strtotime(date("Y") ."-". $i ."-01"))
```

This code assumes you have your month number stored in $i

Comment: Easiest and most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want an array of month names from the beginning of the year to the end e.g. to populate a drop-down select, I would just use the following;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; ++$i) {
  $months[$m] = $m = date("F", strtotime("January +$i months"));
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but wasn't familiar with the syntax, so I would add this as an alternative
`for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 12; $counter ++) {
    $months[$counter] = date('F',  strtotime("December +$counter months"));
}`

Answer (score 10):

adapt as required

```
$m='08';
$months = array (1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar',4=>'Apr',5=>'May',6=>'Jun',7=>'Jul',8=>'Aug',9=>'Sep',10=>'Oct',11=>'Nov',12=>'Dec');
echo $months[(int)$m];
```

Comment: Simple and to the point without unnecessary date conversions.

Answer (score 7):

```
$monthNum = 5;
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
```

I found this on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/change-month-number-to-month-name/ and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in just one line:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $salary->month)->format('F'); //April
```

Answer (score 2):

You need set fields with `strtotime` or `mktime`

```
echo date("F", strtotime('00-'.$result["month"].'-01'));
```

With `mktime` set only month. Try this one:

```
echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $result["month"], 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

this is trivially easy, why are so many people making such bad suggestions? @Bora was the closest, but this is the most robust

```
/***
 * returns the month in words for a given month number
 */
date("F", strtotime(date("Y")."-".$month."-01"));
```

this is the way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Am currently using the solution below to tackle the same issue:

```
//set locale, 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"US");

//set the date to be converted
$date = '2016-08-07';

//convert date to month name
$month_name =  ucfirst(strftime("%B", strtotime($date)));

echo $month_name;
```

To read more about set locale go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

To learn more about strftime go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

`Ucfirst()` is used to capitalize the first letter in a string.

Comment: for a compatibility with utf8 try : utf8_encode(ucfirst(strftime("%B", strtotime($date))));

Comment: @Mimouni This isn't needed as the utf8_encode function converts ISO-8859-1 strings into UTF-8, but through LC_ALL, the code can be instructed to output UTF-8, for example if you use en_US.UTF-8 instead of US.

Answer (score 2):

This for all needs of date-time converting

```
 <?php
 $newDate = new DateTime('2019-03-27 03:41:41');
 echo $newDate->format('M d, Y, h:i:s a');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$days = ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$month = ( date('m') < 10 ) ? date('m')[1] : date('m');
```

That extracts the months.

Answer (score 1):

A simple tricks here you can use strtotime() function workable as per your need, a convert number to month name.

1.If you want a result in Jan, Feb and Mar Then try below one with the 'M' as a parameter inside the date.

```
$month=5;
$nmonth = date('M',strtotime("01-".$month."-".date("Y")));
echo $nmonth;
```

Output : May

/2. You can try with the 'F' instead of 'M' to get the full month name as an output January February March etc.

```
$month=1;
$nmonth = date('M',strtotime("01-".$month."-".date("Y")));
echo $nmonth;
```

Output : January

Answer (score 0):

I think using cal_info() is the easiest way to convert from number to string.

```
$monthNum = sprintf("%02s", $result["month"]); //Returns `08`
$monthName = cal_info(0); //Returns Gregorian (Western) calendar array
$monthName = $monthName[months][$monthNum];

echo $monthName; //Returns "August"
```

See the [docs for cal_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-info.php)

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I did it**

```
// sets Asia/Calcutta time zone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");

//fetches current date and time
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$dateArray = date_parse_from_format('Y/m/d', $date);
$month = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $dateArray['month'])->format('F');
$dateString = $dateArray['day'] . " " . $month  . " " . $dateArray['year'];

echo $dateString;
```

returns `30 June 2019`

Answer (score 0):

This respect the LC_TIME

```
$date = new DateTime('2022-04-05');
$mes = strftime('%B', $date->getTimestamp());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
$name = jdmonthname(gregoriantojd($monthNumber, 1, 1), CAL_MONTH_GREGORIAN_LONG);
```

Answer (score -1):

My approach

```
$month = date('m');
$months_of_year = array(
    array('month' => '01', 'translation' => 'janeiro'),
    array('month' => '02', 'translation' => 'fevereiro'),
    array('month' => '03', 'translation' => 'março'),
    array('month' => '04', 'translation' => 'abril'),
    array('month' => '05', 'translation' => 'maio'),
    array('month' => '06', 'translation' => 'junho'),
    array('month' => '07', 'translation' => 'julho'),
    array('month' => '08', 'translation' => 'agosto'),
    array('month' => '09', 'translation' => 'setembro'),
    array('month' => '10', 'translation' => 'outubro'),
    array('month' => '11', 'translation' => 'novembro'),
    array('month' => '12', 'translation' => 'dezembro'),
);
$current_month = '';
foreach ($months_of_year as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($value['month'] == $month){
        $current_month = $value['translation'];  
        break;  
    }
}
echo("mes:" . $current_month);
```