# Convert Month Number to Month Name query in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

In my table date format is 2011-06-23, but i want to show the month name in string type, like Jan, Feb e.t.c.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php

Comment: Which database are you using? You have selected two different technologies. Do you have really stored data in database with some format (column type is string) or in typed column?

Comment: @Umair *Month Name query in SQL*

Comment: yes date format is 2011-06-23, but want to show in string type, i.e, 06 should be fetched as june,

Comment: You should really decide if you are working with MySQL or SQL Server. They are totally different products

Comment: @Anilbhadula SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, Date_Field)