# i want month name from date function using php

Tags: php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
        $date=date("d:m:Y");
```

Now `$date=14072015;

I want month name 'July' from this date function. i have tried this,but i got output January.

```
$arr1=explode(":",$date);
         $arr2=implode($arr1);
//         print_r($arr2);die;

//        print_r($arr1);die;



//        print_r($date);DIE;
        $year=date("Y");

        $month=date("M",strtotime($arr2));
        print_r($month);DIE;
```

I Want OUTPUT  July.Please help.if anyother methods to solve this please help.

Comment: Would you consider using a different date function? Say straight from time() and not jump hoops as it looks like you are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert number to month name in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php)

Comment: @manjusha Please read my answer. It should solve your issue.

Comment: @manjusha Thanks for accepting my answer. Please vote up my answer if you feel it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php echo date('F', time());?>
```

In your question you are using `$month=date("M",strtotime($arr2));`.

Use `time($arr2)` instead of `strtotime($arr2)`

[DEMO](http://viper-7.com/hy3xeG)

Answer (score 3):

`string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of `time()`.

[Read php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"F" returns the full name of month

```
 <?php echo date('F'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use date function directly in php 
try something like this

```
echo date("F");
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Try this below function

date('F');