# Get value of array from array key passed as parameter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$months = array(
            1 => 'January',
            2 => 'February',
            3 => 'March',
            4 => 'April',
            5 => 'May',
            6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July',
            8 => 'August',
            9 => 'September',
            10 => 'October',
            11 => 'November',
            12 => 'December');
```

I have a function to return the name of the month based on `$month_id` I pass to the function. But the function is always returning `January`. The function I have is as below:

```
public function getMonthNameFromID($month_id)
    {
        $months = array(
            1 => 'January',
            2 => 'February',
            3 => 'March',
            4 => 'April',
            5 => 'May',
            6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July',
            8 => 'August',
            9 => 'September',
            10 => 'October',
            11 => 'November',
            12 => 'December');

        foreach ($months as $m => $m_value) {
            if ($m == $month_id) {
                return $m;
            } else {
                return "0";
            }
        }
    }
```

I need this function to display January when I pass 1 as input, February when 2 is passed as input etc. But the function is currently display only `January` as output.

I have edited the function and I am getting the month name based on index I pass to the function. But is there any way I can make the function more useful by checking if index is an allowed value or any suggestions about a better solution.

```
public function getMonthNameFromID($month_id)
    {
        $months = array(
            1 => 'January',
            2 => 'February',
            3 => 'March',
            4 => 'April',
            5 => 'May',
            6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July',
            8 => 'August',
            9 => 'September',
            10 => 'October',
            11 => 'November',
            12 => 'December');
        if (!empty($month_id)) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                if ($month_id == $i) {
                    return $months[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is in `$month_id`?

Comment: Just `return $months[$month_id];` no need for a loop.

Comment: You should be returning `$m_value`, not `$m`.

Comment: Also duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php

Comment: I have edited the question and is not similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php. The question is about a function that can accept an array key as input and output the array value as ouput

Answer (score 1):

test with this

```
public function getMonthNameFromID($month_id)
    {
        $months = array(
            1 => 'January',
            2 => 'February',
            3 => 'March',
            4 => 'April',
            5 => 'May',
            6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July',
            8 => 'August',
            9 => 'September',
            10 => 'October',
            11 => 'November',
            12 => 'December');

        if(isset($months[$month_id])){
            return $months[$month_id];
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you rewrite the function as follows

```
public function getMonthNameFromID($month_id)
    {
        $months = array(
            1 => 'January',
            2 => 'February',
            3 => 'March',
            4 => 'April',
            5 => 'May',
            6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July',
            8 => 'August',
            9 => 'September',
            10 => 'October',
            11 => 'November',
            12 => 'December');

       return $months[$month_id];
    }
```

Comment: `$months[$month_id]`

Comment: updated, thanks @u_mulder

Comment: i don't see any loop here @LaurensMäkel

Comment: Shouldn't you use $month_Id - 1? Because months Id doesn't start at 0 but at 1, providing a number as 1 wil look for index 1 and return the 2nd month without the -1