# Get the date if the given is month php

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I don't want to use the datepicker because I dont need the year so I create 2 select list where my first select will be the month and the second is the days.

Everything is okay, it will save in my db but here's my problem. I want to display the full name of the month instead of number.

Example:

```
Accounting Period

(Month list)   (Day list)
 0-12             1-31
```

Scenario: I choose oct as my month and 5 is my day.

```
value="10" Oct        value="5"   5
```

**View**

```
Select Month List
    <select name="accounting_period_month">'+
      '<option value="01">January</option>'+
      '<option value="02">February</option>'+
      '<option value="03">March</option>'+
      '<option value="04">April</option>'+
      '<option value="05">May</option>'+
      '<option value="06">June</option>'+
      '<option value="07">July</option>'+
      '<option value="08">August</option>'+
      '<option value="09">September</option>'+
      '<option value="10">October</option>'+
      '<option value="11">November</option>'+
      '<option value="12">December</option>'+
    '</select>
```

It will be save as 10 and 5.

**View in displaying the month list**

```
{{ date('M',strtotime($company_details->accounting_period_month))}}
```

NOTE: Don't mind the **' +** because I append it in my jquery.

Now my question is how can I display the word Oct instead of 10?

Comment: The line `{{ date('M',strtotime($company_details->accounting_period_month))}}` should give you `Oct` not 10 so what is the problem with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert number to month name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php)

Comment: Oct is my select list.

Comment: why do you need to pass 10 at the first place if all you want back is oct?... you can handle it in backend if you have to pass 10 as a number for month

Comment: create a month array define keys as month number and values as month value

Comment: Because the data type of my month/days in my table is int that's why I passed it as number.

Comment: example array(jan,feb,march);

you are getting 1 from database pass that 1 in array
array(1) = you will get jan simple

Comment: use  `Carbon\Carbon::parse(date)->format('M')`

Comment: $monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March

Comment: handle it on php side, 1 to 12 can become your key for , jan feb... ... like this $months = array (1=>"jan", 2=>feb...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799995/get-the-date-if-the-given-is-month-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is multiple way to print month from given number.

**1. date() function along with parameter 'F'**

Code example:

```
$month_num = 10;
echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_num, 10)); //output: October
```

**2. By creating php date object using createFromFormat()**

Code Example

```
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
echo "month name: ".$dateObj->format('F'); // Output: October
```

**3. strtotime() function**

```
echo date("F", strtotime('00-'.$monthNum.'-01')); // Output: October
```

**4. mktime() function**

```
echo date("F", mktime(null, null, null, $monthNum)); // Output: October
```

**5. By using jdmonthname()**

```
$jd=gregoriantojd($monthNum,10,2019);
echo jdmonthname($jd,0); // Output: Oct
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
```

for an older version of PHP

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10)); // March
```

If you want the just 3 letter month name example Mar, you can change F to M. The list of all available formatting options can be found in the [PHP manual documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: May I know what is 10?

Comment: here is the documentation

Comment: mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst);

Comment: as I previously suggested that you can create the array but this is predefined functions of PHP you can directly get month name just by passing month number...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2019,$company_details->accounting_period_month,01)->format('M') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Laravel Tag in your question :

```
$data = YourModel::select('*')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(accounting_period_month) AS month_name')
    ->get();

print_r($data);
```

> See @Karol Samborski comment,

i dont understand whats the issue with the below statement

```
{{ date('M',strtotime($company_details->accounting_period_month))}}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code.

Create a array and define the all month.

Here code for javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 10;
    var month = ["jan", "feb", "march", "april", "may", "jun", "july","aug", 
                 "sep","oct","nov","dec"];
    console.log(month[i-1])

</script>
```

Here code for Php

```
<?php 
   $i = 10;
   $month = array("jan", "feb", "march", "april", "may", "jun", 
                   "july","aug", "sep","oct","nov","dec");
   echo $month[$i-1];
?>
```

Comment: I used jquery/javascript ,this part will be append after I clicked the edit button.

Comment: but you will use PHP first when you retrieve data from the database. at that time only you can easily convert into month name using PHP. there will no need for javascript or JQuery...

Comment: but here u can customize the name of month

Comment: It is better to use code which is already available than creating your own for it... This is known as code reusability...

Comment: example consider C program:

you have one method called factorial() with 10 or 20 lines of code.

when ever you want to calculate factorial you no need to write the function again

you can just call with the function there you used the code this is called code re-usability.