# How do I change the key values after a groupBy in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I've grouped a list of records by the month they were created in:

```
$jobListings = JobListing::with('company')->orderBy('created_at')->get();

$jobListings = $jobListings->groupBy(function($j) {
    return Carbon::parse($j->created_at)->format('m');
});

return response()->json($jobListings);
```

This will give me a JSON object that has records keyed by month in numerical format:

```
{
  "03": [...],
  "04": [...],
}
```

How can I change the keys of this Eloquent collection so that the months read as words like "March" and "April"?

To be clear, what I'd like to output is:

```
{
  "March": [...],
  "April": [...],
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467892/2031033) shows how to convert the numbers to months.

How do I change the keys on this collection after running the `groupBy`?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using  format('F')

```
         return Carbon::parse($j->created_at)->format('F');
```

Comment: @J.A.Streich  for the order the OP should add  an explict order by clause  based on format('m') ..

Comment: I was asking if that was strictly necessary here.  As the objects were already sorted by the create_at prior to the groupBy; and they were in order with the previous groupBy...  So, I was curious if your answer maintains the groupBy of the OP or if another sortBy is necessary with this change.

Comment: The group by return (a natural) sort based on the value returned .. in this case return the string name and not order byb the month order sequence  ..

Comment: `Carbon::parse()` is not needed here because eloquent is already parse it into Carbon instance. Use directly. `$j->created_at->format('F')`