# How to show month name instead of show month digit

Tags: php, html, date

In my current month variable have = `2019-12`  in

```
<p class="col-md-1"><?php echo $cm['month']; ?></p>
```

I want to show `DEC 2019`

Comment: Have a look [in the manual about date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to see how you can format the date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php/18467892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `M Y` in `date()` for the format, and `strtotime` for input date

```
echo date("M Y", strtotime('2019-12'));
```

Answer (score 2):

### You can use [date() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in php

```
<?php
$date = "2019-12";

echo date("M Y", strtotime($date)); // Output : Dec 2019

?>
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for comment but here $date is just a variable for assumed date.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks .. really that was a silly mistake