# How do I get the name of a month

Tags: date, flutter, dart

From the user I receive a `DateTime` variable. I want to get the name of the month that was entered. Is there a way to do so? (Apart from having a bunch of `if` statements)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number to month name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php)

Comment: Use PHP's datetime format method using those format flags listed here: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

`DateFormat("MMMM").format(dateTime);`

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get name of month:

```
List months = ['jan','feb','mar','april','may','jun','july','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var someDateTime = new DateTime.now();
var mon = someDateTime.month;
print(months[mon+1]);
```

don't forget to import package:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it:

> ```
> import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
>
> //--------------------
>
> final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
>
> final DateFormat format1 = DateFormat('MMM');
> final DateFormat format2 = DateFormat('MMMM');
>
> print(format1.format(today)); // abbreviated, exp. : Jan, Feb, Mar
> print(format2.format(today)); // not abbreviated, exp. : January, February,
> ```