# How to convert a string to a date in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to convert a string to date.
The strings i have look like these:

```
$string_jan = '01'; // 01 represents january
$string_feb = '02'; // 02 represents february
...
$string_dec = '12'; // 12 represents december
```

This works fine:

```
$string = '24-09-2020'; 
$date = strtotime($string); 
echo date('M', $date); // output Sep
```

But this does not work:

```
$string = '09'; // month september
$date = strtotime($string); 
echo date('M', $date); // output Jan ??
```

How can i convert this into the first 3 letters of a month using `date`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467669/convert-number-to-month-name-in-php#:~:text=%24monthNum%20%3D%20sprintf(%22%25,0%20to%20make%20it%2008%20.

Comment: How would PHP know if that number is a short year, month, day, hour, minute or second?

Comment: `strtotime` parses complete timestamps which are expected to contain a year, month, day and down to the second. It cannot guess what you want it to do with "09".

Comment: `$month  = '09';
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
$conv_month = $dateObj->format('M'); 
echo $conv_month; // output Sep`